# jq update value based in multiple level filtering

Tags: jq

I want to use jq to update the value of an item based on multiples filterings on multiples levels

What I would like would be to update the list of records of a DNS entry stored in a json file based on the name of the DNS Zone Name and the name of the a_record stored.

For instance having the following list of DNS entries in the file

```
[
  {
    "dns_zone_name": "zone1",
    "a_records": [
      {
        "name": "record1",
        "records": [
          "zone1_record1_item1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "record2",
        "records": [
          "zone1_record2_item1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "dns_zone_name": "zone2",
    "a_records": [
      {
        "name": "record1",
        "records": [
          "zone2_record1_item1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "record2",
        "records": [
          "zone2_record2_item1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expectation would be to being able to modify an specific entry , like the one for zone1/record1

So we would like to have the following answer

```
[
  {
    "dns_zone_name": "zone1",
    "a_records": [
      {
        "name": "record1",
        "records": [
          "New"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "record2",
        "records": [
          "zone1_record2_item1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "dns_zone_name": "zone2",
    "a_records": [
      {
        "name": "record1",
        "records": [
          "zone2_record1_item1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "record2",
        "records": [
          "zone2_record2_item1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But using the following command all records are updated (see https://jqplay.org/s/duVmyZki6r1)

`. |= map (select(.dns_zone_name="zone1" and .a_records[].name=="record1").a_records[].records |= ["NewRecord"])`

And using the following jq command 2 records are updated (see https://jqplay.org/s/RMDzux85cmD)

`.[].a_records |= map (select(.name=="record1").records |= ["NewRecord"])`

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the two conditions, and iterate in between.

Using nested `map` and an inner assignment:

```bash
map(
  select(.dns_zone_name == "zone1").a_records |= map(
    select(.name == "record1").records = ["NewRecord"]
  )
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ljSOPAqJ785)

Using nested `.[]` and an outer assignment:

```bash
( .[]
  | select(.dns_zone_name == "zone1").a_records[]
  | select(.name == "record1").records
) = ["NewRecord"]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HzpqACx-Nfg)

Both produce:

```json
[
  {
    "dns_zone_name": "zone1",
    "a_records": [
      {
        "name": "record1",
        "records": [
          "NewRecord"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "record2",
        "records": [
          "zone1_record2_item1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "dns_zone_name": "zone2",
    "a_records": [
      {
        "name": "record1",
        "records": [
          "zone2_record1_item1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "record2",
        "records": [
          "zone2_record2_item1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note: Replace `=` with `+=` if you want to add the new item to the array (instead of replacing the whole array with one containing just the new item).

Answer (score 0):

I expect there is a more succinct/idiomatic way to do this using `jq`, but here's one way.

```
map(if .dns_zone_name=="zone1"
    then . += (.a_records |= map(if .name=="record1" then .records=["newRecord"] else . end))
    else . 
    end)
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/EXJ0SCd1qFG).